# Compare a searchlist to each row of csv file using Python

Tags: python, search, csv

I have a list of search items:

```
search = ("EPP3424", "EPP5423", "EPP4567", Continues... )
```

I want to check each row of a csv file where each row looks like this:

```
("1206502", "EPP5423", "97334343")
next row...
```

If any of the items in the search list appear in the row of the csv, add that entire row to a new list.

Problem is I can get it to only match one results, I can't seem to get it to loop over the items correctly.

```
csvFile = open(fRoot + "\\SearchEPP.csv", 'r')
try:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        if all(s in row for s in search):
            print "Match"
            allEPP.append(row)
        else:
            print "no match"
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

Python 2.6, Windows 7

UPDATE:

Here's what I tried doing based on your response, still only returns one record.

```
f = open(fRoot + "\\EPP.txt", "r")

search = list()
for row in f:
    search.append(row)

search = set(search)   

#search = ("EPP2383", "EPP2384")

allEPP = list()

csvFile = open(fRoot + "\\SearchEPP.csv", 'r')
try:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        if any(r in search for r in row):
            print "Match"
            allEPP.append(row)
        else:
            print "."
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Better use `set(("EPP3424", "EPP5423", "EPP4567",...))` for (far more) efficient matching.

Comment: Would changing `all` to `any` work? It sounds like you want to flag a row if any of the values are in `search`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if all(s in row for s in search):
```

should probably be:

```
if any(s in row for s in search):
```

---

Note that a better way to do this would be to convert `search` to a set once:

```
search = set(search)
...
```

And then do your check on the `set` (instead of the `tuple`).  Membership tests for `set` are typically O(1) whereas they're O(n) for tuples.

```
if any(r in search for r in row):
```

Or even:

```
if search.intersection(row):
   ...
```

Although the `any` solution *might* be faster (depending on how big `row` is and what the overhead of creating a new set via intersection is versus the overhead of a generator expression).

---

As suggested by @RocketDonkey, you probably have newlines in your "search" list which is still causing you problems in your updated code.  Here's one fix:

```
with open(fRoot + "\\EPP.txt", "r") as f:
    search = set(line.rstrip('\n') for line in f)
```

Comment: @user765015 Have you checked your initial list to make sure that the newlines aren't included?

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- That's a great suggestion.

Comment: Eh, figured if an answer of yours wasn't working it was probably a problem with the input :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey and mgilson THANKS!, YES I do have newlines, works now!

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- Thanks for the vote of confidence.  I was actually pretty puzzled (but I felt good about my answer because MartijnPieters posted the same answer)

Comment: Ha, yeah, that's not a bad confirmation to have :)